# PHP Sequentially naming game ids in a dynamic list of game names

Tags: php

Ever time I make a game of a certain type, say cricket, I have to name it BTAG-n, where n is the number of games made for that type,

eg cricket BTAG-0, cricket BTAG-1, hockey BTAG-0, soccer BTAG-0

I cannot use a database for this, as the the number of different types of games will change with time. So I tried using files.

```
 $filename = '/game_data/'.$name.'.txt';
                                $count = '0';
                                if (!file_exists($filename)){
                                 file_put_contents($filename, $count);
                                }else{
                                    $count = ((int)file_get_contents($filename))+1;
                                    file_put_contents($filename, $count);
                                }
                                $randNumber = "BTAG-".$count;
```

But $count is always 0, I assume because file_put_contents and file_get_contents don't work, and I can't find how to enable errors or change permissions as there is no php.ini file in my cpanel (I inherited this project from another person I have no contact with, maybe he deleted it).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is the question about how to enable "errors" in a script? Because you can use this https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php. Regarding your code, the file path is mostly not writeable since it's the root folder. I would try to remove the "/" at the beginning of your file path.

Comment: could you make the comment about removing the slash an answer so  I can answer it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to write to the root folder of our server, which is most likely not writeable by your PHP process, try to remove the "/" at the beginning of your file path, it will attempt to write the file at the same location of your script.

You might also need the folder "game_data" created there.